# Helm 3.0.2 dry-run + stable/prometheus-operator? Is this supposed to work?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

With Helm v3.0.2 + a new Kubernetes v1.14.9 cluster.

fyi, I've already added the stable repo:

```sh
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
```

```sh
helm install \
  --namespace prometheus \
  prom-dry-run \
  stable/prometheus-operator \
  --dry-run

manifest_sorter.go:175: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:175: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:175: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:175: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:175: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: [unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Alertmanager" in version "monitoring.coreos.com/v1", unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Prometheus" in version "monitoring.coreos.com/v1", unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "PrometheusRule" in version "monitoring.coreos.com/v1", unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "ServiceMonitor" in version "monitoring.coreos.com/v1"]
```

I thought Helm 3 was backward-compatible with existing charts? Is this an exception?

Is prometheus-operator not compatible with Helm 3? Do I have to use Helm 2? Or is there a backward-compatibility option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CRDs were an exception to the Helm v3 chart compatibility, sadly.

The problem is that `--dry-run` can't generate resources using the CRDs, because the CRDs aren't installed by the dry run. This is apparently a ["documented behaviour"](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7449#issuecomment-591498826) although it was documented in the implementation pull-request, not in the Helm Documentation.

Edit: I forgot to mention the best current workaround is to install the CRDs by hand. Then `--dry-run` will work. Helm v3 ignores CRDs that are already installed, so you can just leave them there once you're happy with your configuration and do the install for real.

*Upgrading* CRDs in Helm is a [whole different (not yet resolved) issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5871).

---

`stable/prometheus-operator` gained support to Helm v3 in [8.2.0](https://github.com/helm/charts/pull/18721) in mid-November 2019 so that's not the issue here.

`bitnami/prometheus-operator` gained support in [0.3.0](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/pull/1563) only a couple of days earlier.

Both appear to be actively maintained at the time of writing (March 2020).

---

In case anyone comes looking and is confused that the above two chart names are not links: Both have been renamed, and one has moved.

They are now [prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) (replaces [stable/prometheus-operator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator)) and [bitnami/kube-prometheus](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kube-prometheus) respectively.

Comment: FYI, this (while a very helpful post) is a little out of date. They have updated the documentation for Helm and they also now have some changes. (And also have decided not to ever implement the ability to delete or upgrade CRDs with helm)

Comment: I wouldn't say they have decided to _never_ do it. I would say that there isn't a clear way _to_ do so, and that doing so would require some changes in how Kubernetes itself manages CRDs. There was some interest from a member of the k8s api-machinery SIG (who own CRDs) in exploring such changes, but I can't see any further advance on that since, e.g., https://github.com/helm/community/pull/138#discussion_r475901928

Answer (score 4):

The stable repo is scheduled to be deprecated and probably not updated with latest charts.The canonical source for Helm charts is the [Helm Hub](https://hub.helm.sh). Use below command to add repo and install prometheus operator from Helm Hub using helm 3 or helm 2.

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm install my-prom-release bitnami/prometheus-operator
```

There is a detailed [guide](https://helm.sh/blog/migrate-from-helm-v2-to-helm-v3/) for migrating from helm 2 to helm 3

In helm 3 during a dry run, CRDs are not installed but the Kubernetes validation happens against the output of the chart. So any CR that uses a CRD that is installed by the chart will fail validation during dry run.

**Current work-arounds:**

1.Use helm template instead of dry run

2.Don't reference CRs in the same chart that has the CRDs

3.Install the CRD separately before running the dry run

Comment: the issue is the same for me with the chart from the bitnami repo.

Comment: @flypenguin did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Sankar unfortunately not :(