# Prometheus-operator completely broke down whole Kubernetes cluster on DigitalOcean

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I was trying to install Prometheus Operator in DOKS using Helm. I used this tutorial: [How to Set Up DigitalOcean Kubernetes Cluster Monitoring with Helm and Prometheus Operator](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-digitalocean-kubernetes-cluster-monitoring-with-helm-and-prometheus-operator)

During installation helm chart I got error that cannot create `CRD`. Then I uninstalled the chart and executed command from section *Helm fails to create CRDs* from [Prometheus-operator chart github page](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator) and then installed helm chart. I got error about connection timeout and whole cluster broke down. I cannot connect to it.
After 45 minutes master node got alive and I deleted chart.

I was looking for solution and found this: [Helm 3.0.2 dry-run + stable/prometheus-operator? Is this supposed to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59539621/helm-3-0-2-dry-run-stable-prometheus-operator-is-this-supposed-to-work) (I am using Helm 3) but again whole cluster broke down and after several hours still not working.

I presume that this kind of situation is related to DigitalOcean implementation but I am not sure.

Comment: Are you running `helm install` locally inside the DigitalOcean server, or remotely? If remotely, maybe you are experiencing some connecting issues, you could test monitor the server connectivity or try to run helm install inside the server. Additionally, you could also use `tmux` in server side to don't lost you terminal if connection fails.

Comment: @rabello remotely, but DO cluster has orange icon instead of green and also metrics such as CPU, memory, etc., are not collected. So I do not think this is connection issues.

Comment: It sounds like the metrics collection for Digital Ocean is based on Prometheus, and due to something going wrong in your installation, the existing metrics setup was corrupted. At a guess, the chart has the CRDs are normal objects, not using Helm's CRD-management, and so uninstalling the chart removed the CRDs, which deletes all the objects based on those CRDs. Avoiding exactly this failure is why Helm v3 changed CRD handling.

I don't know why this would affect the cluster's responsiveness though, as it's just affecting the metrics gathering. That's why this is a comment, not an answer. ^_^